# Deploying a NUXT JS app in IIS using IISNode

Tags: nuxt.js, iisnode

I'm trying to deploy a nuxt js app in windows IIS using the IISNODE module. but for the life of me can't get it to work.

I created a server.js file in the root of the repo that has the following code:

```
const express = require('express')
const {Nuxt} = require('nuxt')
const app = express()
const host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
// Import and set Nuxt.js options
let config = require('./nuxt.config.js')
const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)
// Give Nuxt middleware to express
app.use(nuxt.render)
// Listen the server
app.listen(port, host);
console.log('Server listening on ' + host + ':' + port);
```

I then configured a web.config file in IIS with the following code:

```
<!-- indicates that the hello.js file is a node.js application 
to be handled by the iisnode module -->

<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="app/server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="myapp">
      <match url="/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="app/server.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

When I try to run the app I get the following error in IISNode.

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
C:\inetpub\Web\frontend\app\nuxt.config.js:2
export default {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at new Script (vm.js:88:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:263:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:311:10)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1120:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
```

It seems is not accepting the export in the nuxt.config.js file.

Here is my nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  server: {
    port: 2001, // default: 3000
    host: '0.0.0.0' // default: localhost
  },
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ],
    script: [
      {}

    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/toast',
    '@nuxtjs/auth'
  ],
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
    }
  },

  toast: {
    position: 'top-center',
    duration: 1500,
    singleton: false,
    register: [ // Register custom toasts
      {
        name: 'my-error',
        message: 'Oops...Something went wrong',
        options: {
          type: 'error'
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://backend.local/'
  },

  auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'users/authenticate', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
          user: { url: 'user', method: 'get', propertyName: 'authorizedData.user' },
          logout: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

CES

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by applying the Nuxt JS Express template and tweaking the IISNode Web.config preferences.

Comment: could you please explain this a bit more? I have the same issue and I'm unable to resolve.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your nuxt.config.js from:

```
export default {
   ...
}
```

to:

```
module.exports = {
   ...
}
```

I hope it helps